# The length function between the metric space of finite trajectories is not continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Let $T(\mathbb{R}^2)$ set of all trajectories of finit length from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the uniform metric.
And consider the length

$\nabla :T(\mathbb{R}^2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $.
I want to prove that $\nabla$ is not continuous, using the trajectories $\sigma =(x,0)$ and $\sigma_k=(x,\frac{1}{\sqrt k}sen(k\pi x))$ with $x\in [0,1]$ because $\sigma_k \rightarrow \sigma $ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the uniform metric so... I know a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous in X iff every sequence $(x_k)$ in $X$ such that $x_k \rightarrow x$ implies $f(x_k) \rightarrow f(x)$.So this two trajectories really work?

Comment: They work, provided that $\nabla(\sigma_k)\nrightarrow 1$. Did you prove it already?

Comment: A simpler idea is to consider $\sigma_k$ all with the same length by progressively "folding" them. Like, you define $\sigma_1$ as the poligonal linking (0,0), (1/2,1/2), (1,0). Then, to define  $\sigma_2$ you consider the portion of $\sigma_1$ that is above the line $y=1/4$ and "fold" (or reflect) it down, and you get the poligonal linking (0,0), (1/4,1/4), (1/2,0), (3/4, 1/4), (1,0). This "folding" (or reflecting) move does not change the length of the curve and makes it closer to the segment [0,1]. Just keep folding it to define the next $\sigma_k$'s and this sequence will work as well.

Comment: @AndréPorto, I am trying to prove that, por I get $\nabla (\sigma_k)=1$ :c of course, k is a natural number.

Comment: I made a mistake in my calcs, both ideas worked! thanks!